# How to express a field L in the form $M(\sqrt{d})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, roots-of-unity, galois-extensions

If L is the splitting field of $t^{13}-1$,
then obviously $L=\mathbb Q(\zeta_{13})$.
Now an intermediate field $M=\mathbb Q(\zeta_{13}^{12}+\zeta_{13})$. How to express L in the form $M(\sqrt{d})$, where d is in M?

============
I found $[\mathbb Q(\zeta_{13}):\mathbb Q(\zeta_{13}^{12}+\zeta_{13})]=2$. So $\zeta_3$ must satisfy a quadratic equation over $\mathbb Q(\zeta_3^{12}+\zeta_{13})$.But I got stuck here. How can I find such quadratic equation and thus express L in that form?

Comment: I'm guessing all those $\zeta_3$s should be $\zeta_{13}$s.

Comment: Yes they are $\zeta_{13}$! Corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\beta = \zeta_{13} + \zeta_{13}^{-1}$. Then $\zeta_{13}$ is a root of the equation

$x^2-\beta x + 1 = 0$

Notice then that the discriminant $\beta^2-4$ is an element of the real subfield whose square root generates the cyclotomic field.